# How to recieve data with parameter from Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

How to receive data from the service with parameters. I have 2 components and service. From one component I must to receive the data in the other component via the service. Look me code 
header.component.html

```
<li><a routerLink="contact-us">
  <select  (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option>CONTACT US</option>
      <option  *ngFor="let coun of countriesShow">{{ coun }} </option>
  </select>
</a>
</li>
```

header.component.ts

```
  onChange(data: string){
    this.countrySelect = this.ctry.onChange(data);
    return this.countrySelect;
  }
```

selectedcountry.service.ts

```
 public countrySelect: any;

 onChange(selectedCountry: string) {
    this.countrySelect = selectedCountry;
    return this.countrySelect;
}

     getCountry(){
      return this.countrySelect;
      }
```

contact-form.component.ts (this component must to recieve data from header and service)

```
public countrySelect: any;
constructor(private country: SelectedcountryService) { }


ngOnInit() {
   this.countrySelect = this.country.getCountry();
    console.log(this.countrySelect) // undefined
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: variable this.countrySelect is undefined. I want in this variable country which user select from header.component.html dropdown

Comment: have you provided SelectedService in app.module ?

Comment: No. It is important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to set an observable in your service for receiving the data when it changes.

in selectedcountry.service.ts

```
 private countrySubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('');
 public country = this.countrySubject.asObservable();

 public setCountry(country: any) {
    this.countrySubject.next(country);
  }
```

in header.component.ts

```
constructor(private countryService: SelectedcountryService) { }
onChange(selectedCountry: string) {
    this.countrySelect = selectedCountry;
    this.countryService.setCountry(this.countrySelect);
}
```

in contact-form.component.ts

```
constructor(private countryService: SelectedcountryService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.countryService.country.subscribe( (data) => {
    this.countrySelect = data;
    console.log(this.countrySelect);
   });
}
```